Jetpack Compose animated circle
I want to make an animated circle in Jetpack compose to be animated as in the GIF. I couldn't do it the way I wanted. The code block is below.

Colors and lighting effects are unimportant


    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()

    val scale = transition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 1.9f,
        targetValue = if(isAnimating) 2.05f else 1.9f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(durationMillis = 1000, easing = FastOutSlowInEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        )
    )

    val deformFactor = transition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 0f,
            targetValue = if(isAnimating) randomFloatInRange(0.1f, 0.2f) else 0f,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                animation = tween(durationMillis = 1000, easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
            )
        )

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()) {
        val center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
        val radius = 100f * scale.value

        val path = Path()
        path.moveTo(center.x + radius * (1 - deformFactor.value), center.y) 
        for (angle in 0..360 step 10) {
            val rad = Math.toRadians(angle.toDouble())
            val x = center.x + radius * (1 + deformFactor.value * Math.sin(rad * 5)) * Math.cos(rad)
            val y = center.y + radius * (1 + deformFactor.value * Math.sin(rad * 5)) * Math.sin(rad)
            path.lineTo(x.toFloat(), y.toFloat())
        }

        path.close()
        drawPath(path, color.value)
    }


The picture only shows a static image. Please show us the actual animation you want t achieve instead.

I updated it @Leviathan
